# What is the difference between "Asynchronous" and "Syncopated" meters?

Tags: theory, terminology, meter

[image: consecutive measures of 2/4, 9/8, and 7/8 meters]

While working the above problem, I found it difficult to understand the difference between "asynchronous" and "syncopated" meters. I understand that the first meter is a simple duple and the second is a compound triple, but could anyone offer some advice for determining the metric type for the 7/8 measure?

Comment: I have never encountered these terms in this context before. Where did the source question come from?

Comment: @Aaron multiple choice questions sometimes include answer choices that could not be possible for any question.  I suppose this is to make the question easier for those who have at least studied a little bit.  For example, a question on mode identification might have an option for "Hypoaegean."  The fact that a term appears in this context doesn't imply that it's actually used.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to be a multiple-choice question.    Some of the choices include made-up terms.  'Mega Duple' is meaningless.  'Asynchronous' and 'Syncopated' are plausible as musical terms, but are not actually used in this context.

So I seem to have told you which choice is the right answer!

Comment: I've seen pieces that could reasonably be described as employing asynchronous meter.  Similarly, certain meters might reasonably be described as syncopated, for example 4/4 with two groups of three eighth notes and one group of two.  Whether anyone actually has described them as such, I do not know.  I doubt that's what's going on here, though, so +1 from me.

Comment: @phoog Out of curiosity - what are those pieces like, that you would describe their meter as asynchronous?